# How to install protobuf-net for MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop, nant, protobuf-net

I downloaded the latest version of protobuf-net (v2 r480) but I don't know how to install it to use it in MonoDevelop. I can't find a README file or an instruction :( I also tried to build it with nant but it fails http://eugeneciurana.com/pastebin/pastebin.php?show=45036 .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing!

For regular mono and type-first (I.e. DTOs as code), just add the reference and away you go.

If you mean "from .proto", then I don't have any magic IDE add-ins (although I'm open to suggestions). You could use "protogen" at the command line (in your build script) for .proto to c#

If you are using MonoTouch, you might want to use serialization assembly pre-generation - let me know if so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention, that I'm using ArchLinux and I wanted to install the library persistently, so that every project which includes ProtoBuf can use  it. I thought maybe /usr/lib/mono/4.0 might be the right place to put the dll in, but MonoDevelop still isn't aware of it.

Comment: @onny k - in that case I don't know. I would suggest phrasing it as simply "a library dll" - it isn't really a protobuf-net question at that point.